# How to turn on option to store normalized images to my knowledge store

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

The doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-image-scenarios - says "When the imageAction is set to a value other then "none", the new normalized_images field will contain an array of images". How can I do this from the portal? I click "Advanced options" for my indexer, and the only options I see in the "Data to extract" dropdown are: "Content and metadata", "All metadata", and "Storage metadata only". Needless to say, the "normalized_images" field currently is not in my projected objects.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do this from the portal?

It seems that you can't do this with UI but you could achieve it with code.

The `"dataToExtract":"contentAndMetadata"` statement in the configuration parameters. This statement tells the indexer to extract the content from different file formats and the metadata related to each file.

When content is extracted, you can set `imageAction` to extract text from images found in the data source. The `"imageAction":"generateNormalizedImages"` configuration, combined with the OCR Skill and Text Merge Skill, tells the indexer to extract text from the images, and embed it as part of the content field.

You can set the `imageAction` configuration in your [indexer definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-indexer) to `generateNormalizedImages` as shown below:

```
{
  //...rest of your indexer definition goes here ...
  "parameters":
  {
    "configuration": 
    {
        "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
        "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImages"
    }
  }
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-image-scenarios).